# Como remover altitude de ponto em um poligono?

Tags: php

Abaixo segue uma representação de um Polygon em um KML. Veja:

```
<coordinates> 
   -112.2550785337791,36.07954952145647,20 
   -112.2549277039738,36.08117083492122,20 
   -112.2552505069063,36.08260761307279,20 
   -112.2564540158376,36.08395660588506,20 
   -112.2580238976449,36.08511401044813,20 
   -112.2595218489022,36.08584355239394,20 
   -112.2608216347552,36.08612634548589,20 
   -112.262073428656,36.08626019085147,20 
   -112.2633204928495,36.08621519860091,20
   -112.2644963846444,36.08627897945274,20 
   -112.2656969554589,36.08649599090644,20
</coordinates>
```

O ultimo valor da coordenada, ou seja o `20`, representa a altitude, de acordo com [a documentação](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut), no qual não necessito. Então a princípio fiz um `foreach` desta forma abaixo:

```
foreach($names as $coordinate) {
    $coordinates[] = explode( ',20', $coordinate );
 }
```

Porém caso a altitude mude em alguma situação, essa regra no `explode` não funcionará. Qual seria uma forma viável de resolver esse problema e pegar somente as condenadas ignorando a altitude? Uma expressão regular pode resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o ponto poligono é sempre no final da linha e o numero `20` pode ser variante, você pode usar [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) antes de salvar no vetor:

```
<?php

$kml = '
   -112.2550785337791,36.07954952145647,20 
   -112.2549277039738,36.08117083492122,20 
   -112.2552505069063,36.08260761307279,20 
   -112.2564540158376,36.08395660588506,20 
   -112.2580238976449,36.08511401044813,20 
   -112.2595218489022,36.08584355239394,20 
   -112.2608216347552,36.08612634548589,20 
   -112.262073428656,36.08626019085147,20 
   -112.2633204928495,36.08621519860091,20
   -112.2644963846444,36.08627897945274,20 
   -112.2656969554589,36.08649599090644,20';

$kml = preg_replace('#,\d+(\s|$)#', '$1', $kml);

echo $kml;
```

Explicando a regex:

```
 ,\d+(\s|$)
   ^  ^
   |  |------ Pega qualquer espaçamento, como quebra de linha
   |          e espaços, se não tiver então será o `$` que considera
   |          como o final da string
   |
   |---- Pega qualquer numero após a virgula
```